# How to open/read a mysql .err error log

Tags: gnome, mysql

can anyone teach me how to open a MySQL .err log in ubuntu gnome? i tried to use text editor or nano to open it but it is completely blank.
Does it require a special software to open it?

thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. First verify it is a text file.
   That's done with the `file` command. So, <kbd>right click</kbd> → *Open in Terminal* will open a terminal window and then you can verify with:

   ```
   file kelvin-linux.err
   ```

   You should get something like

   ```
   kelvin-linux.err: UTF-8 Unicode text
   ```
2. Then, because of the size, you should use commands like `cat`, `more`, `grep`, `head` or `tail` to explore the file. Editing 418.3MB is not easy.

Good luck.

PS: Usually log files are plain text files.

Comment: it show this
kelvin@kelvin-linux:/opt/lampp/var/mysql$ file kelvin-linux.err
kelvin-linux.err: regular file, no read permission

Comment: with sudo, it say it is a CSV file